# How do get stack to collect the sources?

Tags: haskell, compilation, ghc, haskell-stack

Let's say I want to gather all the dependencies for a package using `stack` on machine A and then compile it with `ghc` on machine B. How do I do that?

The reason I want to this is I'm having trouble installing stack on this one computer, so it would be easier if I could get stack to put into one big Haskell file or something, and then compile it on the other computer.

Comment: do you want to compile stack or build using stack? Because all the dependencies are in the `.cabal` and `stack.yaml` files - you need nothing more (well you'll want the source files) once you installed stack on the target computer

Comment: PS: stack should be easily [installed](http://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/README/#how-to-install) on any system

Comment: @Carsten I am wondering whether there is a way for stack to gather up all the source files to make it easier.

Comment: usually you just `git init` in your project folder and distribute this ;) (it's really just a matter of copy&pasting)

Comment: @Carsten Git init only has the sources for your program, not the dependencies.

Comment: you only need the rest if you cannot use the internet or something ... look if you like you can `cabal get` each of your dependency, and then continue form there but this will get really annoying fast ... obviously I don't understand your problem - maybe another one will - good day

Comment: I've run into such a problem - I ran `cabal install --dependencies  -v3` on machine A (probably an equivalent command for stack exists) to get the actual build plan, then downloaded all those packages, copied them to machine B and installed them. I wouldn't recommend such an endeavor, it will almost certainly be easier to figure out why stack doesn't install on machine B.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of a strange thing to want to do, sorry you are having trouble installing it.

You can use this in bash to unpack all transitive dependencies:

```
stack list-dependencies --separator "-" | while read pkg; do stack unpack $pkg; done
```

(from https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/1843)

You'll also need to be sure to use the correct GHC version, cabal version etc.

Comment: Of course, I should probably just try harder to install it. I should probably read the stack installer thing closer. I'll see whether I do that or this.